# How to get the popover when we touch on the view

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, touch-event

I whant to display the popover on the calenderview like ical application.can any one suggest that one how to do that?please give me the answer.
In ical app that is popover or any touch events.
Is it possible when we touch on the calender view i whant to get the popover?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

I asume you are on an iPad. This calss cannot be used on iPhone devices.

Comment: thank u for responding but this is not usefull.can u suggest any usefull information

Comment: Could you please explain your problem with more detail. What have you tried?

Comment: i have a calenderview with dates.so when i click on the dates i whant to display the popover like ical app.how can i get that one?

Comment: Why UIPopoverController is not usefull?

Comment: Eventview *event =[[Eventview alloc]initWithNibName:@"Eventview" bundle:nil ];
  UIPopoverController *popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:event];
  popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320,480);
  [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Comment: this is my code but this one is when i clicl on the button but iwhant for calenderview on each date how can i get that one?

Comment: heare present popover is added to the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to recognize touch on calendar view.